# Enable debug mode for Lightning Components Blanks Home Page

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am learning lightning web components (lwc). I added a lwc to sales home page. Things work fine. I do see my lwc on the home page. Now I want to debug it in Google Chrome.

I enabled debugging for Lightning Component in setup for my login. But now, when I bring up Sales app home page, nothing is shown. As soon as I disable the debug mode, home page with my component is shown.

What is going on? I want to debug my java script for lwc badly. How can I do that? Without enabling this debugging, java script code is shown as minified which is impossible to debug.

Any help will be appreciated.

Prem

Comment: in chrome's dev tools there is normally a `prettify` code option